# Subtracting days/months/years from a Date object

Tags: javascript, datetime, math

```
var inputDate     = '20/4/2010'.split('/');
var dateFormatted = new Date(parseInt(inputDate[2]), parseInt(inputDate[1]), parseInt(inputDate[0]));

var expiryDate = (dateFormatted.getDate() - 1) + '/' + dateFormatted.getMonth() + '/' + (dateFormatted.getFullYear() + year);
```

This is the Javascript code I'm using to work out an expiry date given a user inputted date. Currently, the expiry date is `original date minus one day and original year minus X`.

The problems with this code, firstly, it doesn't take into account invalid dates. For example, if the user supplied date is '1/10/2010', the expiry date will be '0/10/2013' (assuming the expiry date is +3 years).

I could do something like:

```
var inputDate = '20/4/2010'.split('/');
var day       = parseInt(inputDate[0]);
var month     = parseInt(inputDate[1]);
var year      = parseInt(inputDate[2]);

if (day < 1)
{
    if (month == ...)
    {
        day   = 31
        month = month - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        day   = 30
        month = month - 1;
    }
}

var dateFormatted = new Date(parseInt(inputDate[2]), parseInt(inputDate[1]), parseInt(inputDate[0]));
var expiryDate    = (dateFormatted.getDate() - 1) + '/' + dateFormatted.getMonth() + '/' + (dateFormatted.getFullYear() + year);
```

But more problems arise... Firstly, the code gets a little convoluted. Secondly, this check would have to be done on the day. and then the month. Is there a cleaner, simpler way?

Also, there's a certain circumstance that would involve me needing to calculate the expiry date to the 'end of the month' for that date. For example:

```
Expiry date is: +3 years

User date is: '14/10/2010'
Expiry date is: '31/10/2013'
```

I was hoping the `Date object` would support these calculations but according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date, it seems not...

Comment: momentjs.com makes this way easier: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 11):

Easy way to see if a date inputed is a valid date:

```
var d = Date.parse('4/20/2010');
if (isNaN(d.valueOf())) {
 alert ("bad date value"); 
}
```

Then, here is a dateAdd function that I use regularly.  Extends the Date object, so it's easy to use:

```
Date.prototype.dateAdd = function(size,value) {
    value = parseInt(value);
    var incr = 0;
    switch (size) {
        case 'day':
            incr = value * 24;
            this.dateAdd('hour',incr);
            break;
        case 'hour':
            incr = value * 60;
            this.dateAdd('minute',incr);
            break;
        case 'week':
            incr = value * 7;
            this.dateAdd('day',incr);
            break;
        case 'minute':
            incr = value * 60;
            this.dateAdd('second',incr);
            break;
        case 'second':
            incr = value * 1000;
            this.dateAdd('millisecond',incr);
            break;
        case 'month':
            value = value + this.getUTCMonth();
            if (value/12>0) {
                this.dateAdd('year',value/12);
                value = value % 12;
            }
            this.setUTCMonth(value);
            break;
        case 'millisecond':
            this.setTime(this.getTime() + value);
            break;
        case 'year':
            this.setFullYear(this.getUTCFullYear()+value);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error('Invalid date increment passed');
            break;
    }
}
```

Then just use:

```
 var d = new Date();
 d.dateAdd('day', -1).dateAdd('year', 3);
```

T'da

Comment: I think this answer is the best solution and the date you are parsing in the example is a little icing on the cake. Thanks!

Comment: Just a side comment, the validation is good, however don't call the prototype with the parsed variable d. You obviously need to instantiate this into a Date object. Otherwise you'll get goofy errors, of "dateAdd, does not exist."

var d = Date();
d.dateAdd('day', -1).dateAdd('year', 3);

Comment: I think this is not correct solution.
I wanted person should be elder then 18 years based on birth date.
tried to subtract 18 years from current date(28-march-2014), this solution returned 28-Feb-1996.

I cross verified answer from http://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=28&m1=3&y1=2014&type=sub&ay=18&am=&aw=&ad=

and 

http://www.calculator.net/date-calculator.html?today2=03%2F28%2F2014&c2op=-&c2year=18&c2month=0&c2week=0&c2day=0&calctype=op&x=98&y=11

The date I got was 28-March-1996

So I think something is missing.

Comment: month in the JavaScript date object is zero-indexed, so month 2 is March. January=0, February=1, March=2, etc...

Comment: How has this not reached 100 upvotes yet. This is a fantastic answer for those who don't want to rely on plugins all the time and want a more manual approach to a simple solution!

Comment: This answer assumes all days are 24 hours long, which is not correct twice per year where daylight saving is observed. Also, adding/subtracting the parts one at a time can lead to different results than adding/subtracting all at once. Similarly doing addition/subtraction in a different order. It's also illogical to adjust hours by setting minutes, days by setting hours, etc. and it cascades down all the sub units - adding a day will call recursively call the function 4 times, so very inefficient.

Answer (score 5):

A similar question has been answered here:

[How to add/subtract dates with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931288/how-to-add-subtract-dates-with-javascript)

Similar thing can be done for months and years.

For e.g.

```
     var date = new Date('2011','01','02');
     alert('the original date is '+date);
     var newdate = new Date(date);
     newdate.setMonth(newdate.getMonth() - 7);
     var nd = new Date(newdate);
     alert('the new date is '+nd);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var currentDate = new Date(year,month,day);
var expiryDate = new Date();
expiryDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + (3 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

using the number of seconds past 1970 is fine for this :-)
oh, you have more rules. well after that you will still have to check for those cases...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely sure how that works... What does each number represent? How would I calculate +4 years on top of a given date using that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be useful to you: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation