# How to add/subtract dates with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to let users easily add and subtract dates using JavaScript in order to browse their entries by date.

The dates are in the format: "mm/dd/yyyy". I want them to be able to click a "Next" button, and if the date is: " 06/01/2012" then on clicking next, it should become: "06/02/2012". If they click the 'prev' button then it should become, "05/31/2012".

It needs to keep track of leap years, number of days in the month, etc.

Any ideas?

P.S using AJAX to get the date from the server isn't an option, its a bit laggy and not the experience for the user that the client wants.

Comment: if you are using datepicker . then `dateValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", '06/01/2012');` `dateValue.setDate(dateValue.getDate()+1);`

Answer (score 100, accepted):

**Code:**

```js
var date = new Date('2011', '01', '02');
alert('the original date is ' + date);
var newdate = new Date(date);

newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() - 7); // minus the date

var nd = new Date(newdate);
alert('the new date is ' + nd);
```

**Using Datepicker:**

```
$("#in").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       var actualDate = new Date(dateText);
       var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate()+1);
        $('#out').datepicker('option', 'minDate', newDate );
    }
});

$("#out").datepicker();​
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2qzjg/)

Extra stuff that might come handy:

```
getDate()   Returns the day of the month (from 1-31)
getDay()    Returns the day of the week (from 0-6)
getFullYear()   Returns the year (four digits)
getHours()  Returns the hour (from 0-23)
getMilliseconds()   Returns the milliseconds (from 0-999)
getMinutes()    Returns the minutes (from 0-59)
getMonth()  Returns the month (from 0-11)
getSeconds()    Returns the seconds (from 0-59)
```

**Good link:** [MDN Date](http://jsfiddle.net/2YkeK/)

Comment: Why create a 3rd new date: var nd = new Date(newdate)?? The date object, newdate, as adjusted by .setDate is just fine, isn't it?

Comment: @KevinM yep, depends on the purpose so the `nd` is new date `var` was just created for clarity! `:)`

Answer (score 42):

You need to use `getTime()` and `setTime()` to add or substract the time in a javascript Date object.  Using `setDate()` and `getDate()` will lead to errors when reaching the limits of the months 1, 30, 31, etc..

Using setTime allows you to set an offset in milliseconds, and let the Date object figure the rest:

```
var now=new Date();
var yesterdayMs = now.getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*1; // Offset by one day;
now.setTime( yesterdayMs );
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. The Date constructor seems to behave strangely when a negative number is used for the day index. I found the only way to resolve it was to work with milliseconds directly

Comment: Best solution!. All the other solutions using setDate should be downvoted... could have safed me a lot of trouble...

Comment: Ditto. This is the cleanest and more reliable solution. Thank you @decasteljau

Answer (score 15):

```
startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate() - daysToSubtract);


startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate() + daysToAdd);
```

Answer (score 8):

The JavaScript `Date` object can help here.

The first step is to convert those strings to `Date` instances. That's easily done:

```
var str = "06/07/2012"; // E.g., "mm/dd/yyyy";
var dt = new Date(parseInt(str.substring(6), 10),        // Year
                  parseInt(str.substring(0, 2), 10) - 1, // Month (0-11)
                  parseInt(str.substring(3, 5), 10));    // Day
```

Then you can do all sorts of useful calculations. JavaScript dates understand leap years and such. They use an idealized concept of "day" which is *exactly* 86,400 seconds long. Their underlying value is the number of milliseconds since The Epoch (midnight, Jan 1st, 1970); it can be a negative number for dates prior to The Epoch.

More on the [MDN page on `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

You might also consider using a library like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com), which will help with parsing, doing date math, formatting...

Comment: dont stuff around with dates people. Just use moment.js and save your hair.

Comment: It's 2020 and the MomentJS developers now consider it a legacy project.

Comment: @DiomidisSpinellis - Hey, breaking news! :-) (Literally last month.) But note that it's not going anywhere, they just aren't adding any new features. They're still maintaining it. I haven't felt the need for a new feature in it in years, so... Anyway, hopefully `Temporal` moves forward at a good pace, but its API is still a (slightly) moving target...

Comment: Agreed. No need to jump ship if you're already using MomentJS, but I wouldn't adopt it for a new project, unless there's a very compelling need.

Comment: Also, JavaScript which isn't browser based (as in it is embedded in an application) may not have the library whitelisted; in those cases, knowing how to get the answer without the library is crucial.

Answer (score 4):

```
//In order to get yesterday's date in mm/dd/yyyy.


function gimmeYesterday(toAdd) {
            if (!toAdd || toAdd == '' || isNaN(toAdd)) return;
            var d = new Date();
            d.setDate(d.getDate() - parseInt(toAdd));
var yesterDAY = (d.getMonth() +1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
$("#endDate").html(yesterDAY);
        }
$(document).ready(function() {
gimmeYesterday(1);
});
```

you can try here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQAHE/

Answer (score 3):

May be this could help

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function AddDays(toAdd) {
            if (!toAdd || toAdd == '' || isNaN(toAdd)) return;
            var d = new Date();
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + parseInt(toAdd));

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = d.getDate() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
        }

function SubtractDays(toAdd) {
            if (!toAdd || toAdd == '' || isNaN(toAdd)) return;
            var d = new Date();
            d.setDate(d.getDate() - parseInt(toAdd));

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = d.getDate() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
        }
    </script>
    ---------------------- UI ---------------
        <div id="result">
        </div>
        <input type="text" value="0" onkeyup="AddDays(this.value);" />
        <input type="text" value="0" onkeyup="SubtractDays(this.value);" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Working with dates in javascript is always a bit of a hassle. I always end up using a library. Moment.js and XDate are both great:

http://momentjs.com/

http://arshaw.com/xdate/

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/39fWa/

```
var $output = $('#output'),
    tomorrow = moment().add('days', 1);

$('<pre />').appendTo($output).text(tomorrow);

tomorrow = new XDate().addDays(-1);

$('<pre />').appendTo($output).text(tomorrow);
```

​

Comment: I've seen times when moment.js calculates an invalid number of months during a date interval (diff) - for instance, between the dates of Feb 13, 2014 and Mar 15, 2016 - moment.js will report that there are 26 months when most languages with built in Date or DateTime classes of some sort will report this same interval as 25. XDate seems to calculate that interval correctly though.

Answer (score 2):

The way I like, is if you have a date object you can subtract another date object from it to get the difference. Date objects are based on milliseconds from a certain date.

```
var date1 = new Date(2015, 02, 18); // "18/03/2015", month is 0-index
var date2 = new Date(2015, 02, 20); // "20/03/2015"

var msDiff = date2 - date1; // 172800000, this is time in milliseconds
var daysDiff = msDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24; // 2 days
```

So this is how you subtract dates. Now if you want to add them? date1 + date2 gives an error.. But if I want to get the time in ms I can use:

```
var dateMs = date1 - 0;
// say I want to add 5 days I can use
var days = 5;
var msToAdd = days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 
var newDate = new Date(dateMs + msToAdd);
```

By subtracting 0 you turn the date object into the milliseconds format.

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = new Date('your date string here'); // e.g. '2017-11-21'

var newdate = new Date(date.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000 * days) // days is the number of days you want to shift the date by
```

This is the only solution that works reliably when adding/subtracting across months and years. Realized this after spending way too much time mucking around with the getDate and setDate methods, trying to adjust for month/year shifts.

decasteljau (in this thread) has already answered this but just want to emphasize the utility of this method because 90% of the answers out there recommend the getDate and setDate approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native javascript Date object to keep track of dates. It will give you the current date, let you keep  track of calendar specific stuff and even help you manage different timezones. You can add and substract days/hours/seconds to change the date you are working with or to calculate new dates.

take a look at this object reference to learn more:

[Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

All these functions for adding date are wrong. You are passing the wrong month to the Date function. More information about the problem : 
http://www.domdigger.com/blog/?p=9

Answer (score 1):

The best date utility I've used is [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) for a few reasons:

- Uses the native JavaScript `Date` format.
- Immutable; built using pure functions and always returns a new date instance instead of changing the passed one.
- Modular; import just the functions you need.

Package manager:

`"date-fns": "^1.30.1"`

Code:

`import { addDays, subDays } from 'date-fns'`

```
let today = new Date()
let yesterday = subDays(today, 1)
let tomorrow = addDays(today, 1)
```

Simple and awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Something I am using (jquery needed), in my script I need it for the current day, but of course you can edit it accordingly.

HTML:

```
<label>Date:</label><input name="date" id="dateChange" type="date"/>
<input id="SubtractDay" type="button" value="-" />
<input id="AddDay" type="button" value="+" />
```

JavaScript:

```
    var counter = 0;

$("#SubtractDay").click(function() {
    counter--;
    var today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + counter);
    var formattedDate = new Date(today);
    var d = ("0" + formattedDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var m = ("0" + (formattedDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var y = formattedDate.getFullYear();
    $("#dateChange").val(d + "/" + m + "/" + y);
});
$("#AddDay").click(function() {
    counter++;
    var today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + counter);
    var formattedDate = new Date(today);
    var d = ("0" + formattedDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var m = ("0" + (formattedDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var y = formattedDate.getFullYear();
    $("#dateChange").val(d + "/" + m + "/" + y);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noyot2yq/)

Answer (score 0):

if you use the `moment.js`

examples:

```
moment(currentDate).add('days',3) // adds 3 days
moment(currentDate).subtract('days',3) // 3 days subtract
```

or

```
moment(currentDate).add('hours',3) // adds 3 hour
moment(currentDate).subtract('hours',3) // 3 hour subtract
```