# How to get the months between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I'm using jquery `datepicker` in order to get 2 dates. In my case I have to get the date in this format `d-M-y`. I'm using it in order to be able to insert the values into an `oracle` database without any formating. The problem is that I need to calculate the months between 2 dates. For example: `1-Oct-13` - `30-Oct-16`.

Here is how I'm getting the dates in my js:

```
LastAssimDatePicker = (function() {
                        $( "#lastAssimilationDate" ).datepicker({
                            yearRange: "-20:+100",
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            dateFormat: "d-M-y"
                        });
                    }),

LastAssimDateOverPicker = (function() {
                        $( "#lastAssimilationDateOver" ).datepicker({
                            yearRange: "-20:+100",
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            dateFormat: "d-M-y"
                        });
                    }),
```

The above dates are assigned to `2 variables` - `lastAssimilationDate` and `LastAssimDateOver`

The problem is that I really can't find a way to calculate the months between the 2 dates and I already lost about 2 hours on it. I'm pretty sure that there will be an easy solution, but as a beginner, I'm not able to spot it. I know that there are simmilar topics here, but I can't get it working, or it does not fit on my issue.

Comment: `I need to calculate the months between 2 dates` can you show an example dates?

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea on how to do it...

Comment: Do you want to know how many month the range contains ?

Comment: That means no. of months between `1-Oct-13 - 30-Oct-16`?

Comment: Your question has already been answered. See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: @GavinOwen yes, but is there a way to do it without changing the date format?

Comment: This post answers too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you are not supposed to change the format I have a solution for you.

With the help of @T.J. Crowder's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2536445/1671639), I done this

```
d1 = new Date($( "#lastAssimilationDate" ).val());
d2 = new Date($( "#lastAssimilationDateOver").val());
alert(monthDiff(d1, d2));
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/mB6B7/1/)

Not sure `Nan` is popping, but I am able to see difference.

[image]

Comment: @Slim But I'm able to get the month difference.  Not sure about the `Nan` check the picture in my answer.

Comment: Wow what I noticed is that it is not working under firefox and IE.

Comment: @Slim You got it, I'm able to reproduce here in FF.  Let me try and come back with some solution

Comment: I will also be looking. I hope that it can be fixed. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/w54pq/ *or* in case you want both month included try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yQyJq/

This will fit your need, there can be many version for it.

Please note there can be various combinations with your need so feel free to play around with this code.

Old link one of which is my old reply:

- [How to add/subtract dates with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931288/how-to-add-subtract-dates-with-javascript/10931362#10931362)
- [Difference in Months between two dates in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Hope this helps `:)`

**code**

```
$('.start,.end').datepicker();

$('.hulk').click(function () {
    var sDate = $('.start').val();
    var nDate = $('.end').val();

    var startdate = new Date(sDate);
    var enddate = new Date(nDate);

    enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate() - startdate.getDate());
    alert(monthDiff(startdate,enddate));
});


function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
```

**Working shot**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
    function calcualteMonthYr(){
    var fromDate =new Date($('#txtFrom').val()); //datepicker (text fields)
    var toDate = new Date($('#txtTo').val()); // datepicker

     var months;
        months = (toDate.getFullYear() - fromDate.getFullYear()) * 12;
        months += toDate.getMonth();
        if (toDate.getDate() < fromDate.getDate())
        {
            months--;
        }
    $('#txtTimePeriod2').val(months);
}
// it also consider dates so you would get exact months ..
```