# Javascript time that display current and +1 date

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 48 hour timeline. I'm utilizing the JavaScript date function. I am looking for the following format and I am not sure how to achieve it. I want to display today's date and the next day.

DD - DD+1 MMM YY

```
    <script> 
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getDate();
        document.write(n);

    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/deaconf19/bGm6c/

Thanks

Comment: What the heck does `DD - DD+1 MMM YY` mean? Seems like a strange format!

Comment: @adeneo I am guessing it means something like `24-25 April 2014` (or `04` or `4`, instead of `April`), where `24` is today's day date.

Comment: Correct I did not mean for it to be a literal translation of what I am using

Comment: What happens at the end of the month? What it look like on April 30? Or for that matter, what would it look like on December 31?

Comment: I can post answer if you come up with answer to above questions. good points @p.s.w.g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();

var month = new Array();
month[0]="Jan";
month[1]="Feb";
month[2]="Mar";
month[3]="Apr";
month[4]="May";
month[5]="Jun";
month[6]="Jul";
month[7]="Aug";
month[8]="Sep";
month[9]="Oct";
month[10]="Nov";
month[11]="Dec";

var m = month[d.getMonth()];
var d1 = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var m1 = month[d1.getMonth()];

$("#date").append(d.getDate() + " " + m + " " + d.getFullYear() + " - " + d1.getDate() + " " + m1 + " " + d1.getFullYear());
```

Here take a look
http://jsfiddle.net/N0ir/bGm6c/4/

Comment: This doesn't handle end-of-the-month or end-of-the-year dates. For instance, if the current day is April 30 (remember there's no 31st day in April), then the output for this is incorrectly `30 - 31 Apr 2014`. Likewise, for New Year's Eve (Dec. 31), it is `31 - 32 Dec 2014`. This is because [`Date.prototype.getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) returns the *day-of-the-month number*, and nothing else.

Comment: @ajp15243 very noob of me not to see it, made adjustments

Comment: @N0ir Well, now it says `30 - 1 Apr 2014` :)

Comment: You'll need to make either a ternary condition to see if d1 is less than d in the new code. Then if so change month or don't add it at all. Least that's what I would do

Comment: @N0ir +1 Looks to work to me! Although, if you want to get really technical, I just remembered that leap years are still something to consider, but there's a lot more logic to checking if the current year is a leap year.

Comment: @ajp15243 It should cover leap years too. [28 Feb 2015 - 1 Mar 2015] and [28 Feb 2016 - 29 Feb 2016]

Comment: @N0ir Oh yes, you are right, that logic would be handled by `Date`'s constructor when instantiating `d1`.

Comment: thanks for the update I was going to post how this is showing 32 days instead of the first of next month

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var tomorrow= new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script> 
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getDate(); 
            var tomorrow = new Date();
            tomorrow.setDate(n+1);
            document.write(n);
            document.write(" ");
            document.write(tomorrow.getDate());
    </script>
```

Comment: @JeremyA1 - At least it is until the end of the month, but you're always welcome back in 6 days.

Comment: @adeneno - You are correct it now displays 32 days instead of first of the month. I found a fix on here but when I implement it it shows a long string like a ticker

Comment: hm, strage - it works for me -> 30 and then 01 http://jsfiddle.net/acidrat/f8D4h/ but anyway you have already found your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have your date in `d`:

```
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1); // add 1 day to d
```

This is basically the in situ variation of @ambarox' answer.

The generalizations should be obvious ...

The standalone version for the op's code:

```
<script> 
    var d = new Date()
      , t = new Date()
      ;

    t.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    if (d.getMonth() === t.getMonth()) {
        document.write(d.getDay() + " - ");
    }
    else {
        if (d.getYear() === t.getYear()) {
            document.write(d.getDay() + "." + d.getMonth());
        }
        else {
            document.write(d.getDay() + "." + d.getMonth() + "." + d.getYear());
        }
    }
    document.write(" - " + t);
</script>
```

More details on how to add/subtract different time and date values and on what methods are available to do are cited in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931362/).