# JQuery datepicker - limit End_Date to 52 weeks

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using two JQuery datepicker widgets in a form:

```
<p><label>Start Date:</label> </p><p>
    <input type="text" id="Start_Date" name="Start_Date" class="date-pick smallInput required"/>*
    </p>

    <p><label>End Date:</label> </p><p>
    <input type="text" id="End_Date" name="End_Date" class="date-pick smallInput required"/>*
```

Any idea how to limit End_Date to 52w after Start_date?

I have had a read through the JQuery UI http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ but can't see anything on this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/mj7Hy/

So, given that `:)` `52 weeks == 364 days`

Also you might find this useful : [How to add/subtract dates with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931288/how-to-add-subtract-dates-with-javascript/10931362#10931362)

Hope this helps man!

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dt1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var date2 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 364);
            $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
            $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
        }
    });
    $('#dt2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        onClose: function () {
            var dt1 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            console.log(dt1);
            var dt2 = $('#dt2').datepicker('getDate');
            if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                var minDate = $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            }
        }
    });
});
```