# Displaying Yesterday's Date

Tags: javascript

How can the following code be modified to display yesterday's date instead of today's date? For example, "Sunday, February 1, 2015", should become "Saturday, January 31, 2015".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  // Array of day names
  var dayNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
  // Array of month Names
  var monthNames = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
  var now = new Date();
  document.write(dayNames[now.getDay()] + ", " + 
  monthNames[now.getMonth()] + " " + 
  now.getDate() + ", " + now.getFullYear());
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931288/how-to-add-subtract-dates-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a line `now.setDate(now.getDate()-1);` it will set the Date to yesterday's date.

```
  var dayNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
  var monthNames = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
  var now = new Date();
  now.setDate(now.getDate()-1);
  document.write(dayNames[now.getDay()] + ", " + 
  monthNames[now.getMonth()] + " " + 
  now.getDate() + ", " + now.getFullYear());
```