# Handling day subtraction in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Funny thing is happening when trying to subtract a day off the current date in JavaScript.

Here is what is going on:

```
var d = new Date($(".nav-tabs li").first().find('.specific-date').text());
d = new Date(d.getTime() - (24*60*60*1000));
```

`d` is set from a `JQuery` button click.  `Date examples going in would be, 04/7/2015.`  Subtract that time by milliseconds. For example, lets say I log todays current date subtracted by one day.

`Mon Apr 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)` is my output which is correct.

Now when I implement this into a slide bar that you are able to go up a date and down a date, this is what goes on.

```
$(".nav-tabs li").last().remove();
if(d.getDay() == 0)
{
    $(".arrow-left").after('<li role="presentation"><a href="#">
<span class="specific-day">'+weekday[6]+'</span><br/>
<span class="specific-date">' + d.getMonth() + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' +  d.getFullYear()+'
</span></a></li>');
}
else
{
    $(".arrow-left").after('<li role="presentation"><a href="#">
<span class="specific-day">'+weekday[d.getDay() - 1]+'
</span><br/><span class="specific-date">' + d.getMonth() + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' +  d.getFullYear()+'
</span></a></li>');
}
```

`weekday` is an array that contains abbreviations of the current day.

Here is how this is declared.

```
var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0]=  "Mon";
    weekday[1] = "Tue";
    weekday[2] = "Wed";
    weekday[3] = "Thu";
    weekday[4] = "Fri";
    weekday[5] = "Sat";
    weekday[6] = "Sun";
```

Now my issue running into this is, the `month` each time the date is subtracted by `one` day is also subtracted by `one` month.

**Example:**

`Mon Apr 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)` becomes `Mon Mar 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)` on the last section where `JQuery` implements the new results.

Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this could answer your question better than me

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931288/how-to-add-subtract-dates-with-javascript

Comment: @matthammond its helpful but not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving to `moment.js` it provides a phenomenal library and ease of use with great functions.

Here is what I did:

```
var d = moment($(".nav-tabs li").first().find('.specific-date').text());
d = d.subtract(1, 'days') ;// 1
$(".nav-tabs li").last().remove();
$(".arrow-left").after('<li role="presentation"><a href="#"><span class="specific-day">'+d.format("ddd")+'</span><br/><span class="specific-date">' + d.format("MM") + '/' + d.format("DD") + '/' +  d.format("YYYY")+'</span></a></li>');
```

Eliminated many lines.