# How Can I show the previous month only in my calendar?

Tags: html

This is my `html` code:

```
<div class="input-group input-medium date date-picker"
    data-date=""
    data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd"
    data-date-viewmode="years"
    data-date-minviewmode="months"
    data-date-end-date="+0d">
    <input name="water.month" type="text" value="${water?.month}" class="form-control" id="months">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to show the previous month only in my calendar . How Can I do it?

Comment: What datepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: bootstrap datepicker

Comment: RTM: [`startDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#senddate) and [`endDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate).

Comment: it's not working.

Comment: Please define 'not working', and update your question with what you've tried. Even better, put together a jsFiddle to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, You want to display only one month (Previous Month). If so, Try this:

```
<div id='myDate'>
    <input type="text" type="text" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var now = new Date();
var prevMonthFirstDate = new Date(now.getFullYear() - (now.getMonth() > 0 ? 0 : 1), (now.getMonth() - 1 + 12) % 12, 1);
var prevMonthLastDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 0);
$('#myDate input').datepicker({
startDate: prevMonthFirstDate,
endDate: prevMonthLastDate
});
```

To understand how to get the first day of the month, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169116/get-the-first-and-last-day-of-the-previous-month-jquery)

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtkukgvp/3/)