# How to get last month date in java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get specific date in java script.

What I am trying to do is.
I have variable called `frequency` Which can be `Daily` , `Weekly` and `Monthly`

```html
if(frequency=="daily")
{
    date='current_date -2 days';
}
    else if ( frequency== 'weekly')
{
    date='current_date -8 days';
}
    else if ( frequency == 'monthly')
{
    date='current_date -32 days';
}
```

This is the way I get current date with required format.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var hh = today.getHours();
var min = today.getMinutes();
var ss = today.getSeconds();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

//  today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

today = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd + " " + hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss ;
alert("Today's date :"+today);
```

But, I am facing problem in subtracting the days

can anyone give an idea how can I achieve this.

Comment: check out this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931288/how-to-add-subtract-dates-with-javascript

Comment: 'current_date -2 days' is string. try `current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() - 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```js
function setDate(frequency) {
  var today = new Date(),
    date;
  if (frequency == "daily") {
    date = today.getTime() - (2*24*60*60*1000); // 2 days 24 hrs 60 mins 60 secs 1000 ms
  } else if (frequency == 'weekly') {
    date = today.getTime() - (8*24*60*60*1000);
  } else if (frequency == 'monthly') {
    date = today.getTime() - (32*24*60*60*1000);
  }
  return new Date(date);
}

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = setDate('monthly');
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

You need to convert days into time in `ms` *miliseconds* to convert it in time then you can subtract it from current time in `ms` after it you can return it as a `new Date(date);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://momentjs.com/ which makes date manipulation a breathe.