# Jquery Countdown how to calculate remaining Months from 0-12?

Tags: jquery

What's the best way to calculate the remaining months left on a countdown timer?

I'm using jquery to countdown to a date in the future that is over 12 months away, in fact far longer than 10 years away.

How would I show months from 0-12 based on how much time is left?
So for example the timer could show x Years and 5 Months remaining resetting to 12 once it hits 0.

I'll be replacing the "weeks" with months, but I'm not sure how to calculate it.

```
                weeks = Math.floor(left/60/60/24/7),
```

Comment: Have you considered using the Date object? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18424817/575828

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be what you're looking for:

```
function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
```

Source: [Difference in Months between two dates in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

That will give you the total number of months between the two dates, after which you can use the modulus operator to get the number you need: `monthDiff(yourDate1, yourDate2) % 12`

Comment: He He!
Why thank you sir, worked like a charm :) 
As soon as I find the link to mark this as the answer you got it!
For anyone else wondering, I had a little trouble calling the function using the current date as one of the variables (who knows why I think I had an extra set of brackets) but this works -
`monthDiff(new Date(), yourDate2 ) % 12,`