# How do i add years, months, days, hours, minutes or seconds to JavaScript Date object?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, date-arithmetic

I often encountered the situation where I want to add years, months, days, hours, minutes or seconds to a Date object in JavaScript. There are many ways described for each *specific* "add" (edit: as in add day for example) but I didn't find a complete solution on stackoverflow yet, so I decided to share my approach in [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) style. [My own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53338200/2556142) is a way to deal with the problem without using a framework.

---

*Other solutions to the Problem suggested in comments and answers:*

**Frameworks/Libraries dealing with the problem:**

[moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/) (thanks JonnyIrving/Eugene Mihaylin/Pac0)

https://blog.bitsrc.io/9-javascript-date-time-libraries-for-2018-12d82f37872d (thanks RobG)

[fecha.js](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) (thanks RobG)

**Examples of specific add topics** (thanks Pac0):

Days: [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Minutes: [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Hours: [Adding hours to Javascript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

Months: [JavaScript function to add X months to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date/2706169)

---

*(I will not mark any answer as accepted because in my opinion there are multiple valid ways)*

Comment: related: how-to-add-subtract-dates-with-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931288/how-to-add-subtract-dates-with-javascript

Comment: related: incrementing-a-date-in-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: related: add-days-to-javascript-date https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date

Comment: @Pac0 Yes I explicitly wrote "There are many ways decribed for each specific add"... You are just posting some of those...

Comment: Well, I think it's a good thing to reference some of them here. Anyway, I think that your question is actually a duplicate of the first linked, though.

Comment: related : adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Comment: First one is also just adding days - but yes reference is actually fine. I will include some in the question. Thanks for contribution.

Comment: related : how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object

Comment: related : javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date/2706169

Comment: related: how-to-add-months-to-a-date-in-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645058/how-to-add-months-to-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: adjusted my question to include some of those examples. Thanks Pac0. However, the topic why the question has been marked as duplicate is really not the same...

Comment: Moment.js isn't a framework, it's a library. And there are many others, there are 9 listed in the article [*9 Javascript Time and Date Manipulation Libraries for 2018*](https://blog.bitsrc.io/9-javascript-date-time-libraries-for-2018-12d82f37872d). There is also [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha), which is  a great parsing and formatting library that is very easy to extend with arithmetic methods.

Answer (score 2):

You may not be inclined to introduce a library to solve this problem and I understand sometimes it's better to do it vanilla, but personally, I find that all the headaches of dealing with dates and times in JS become a whole lot easier when you introduce the Moment.js library.

You can take a look at the doc here:https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/

Below I have shown what it can do in terms of the adding of units of time but as you will see from the docs it does a whole lot more. It's really good at formatting date objects for example.

```js
moment(new Date());

var nowPlusYear = moment().add(1, 'year');
var nowPlusMonth = moment().add(1, 'month');
var nowPlusMinute = moment().add(1, 'minute');

console.log("In 1 year it will be", nowPlusYear);
console.log("In 1 month it will be", nowPlusMonth);
console.log("In 1 minute it will be", nowPlusMinute);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Anyways check it out and see what you think.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, I added the link in the original question. I think I will not mark any answer as accepted because in my opinion there are multiple valid ways (as of now I would mark this one and mine). Have an upvote tho.

Comment: Sure no problem! Great edits to the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Try to get out of JS date hell and use the widely used [moment.js library](https://momentjs.com/guides/) :

```
moment('2018-01-01').add(1, 'day'); 

moment('2018-01-01').add(1, 'hour');
```

etc...

Answer (score -1):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
moment('2000-01-01').add(1, 'year');
moment('2000-01-01').add(1, 'month');
moment('2000-01-01').add(1, 'days');
moment('2000-01-01').add(1, 'hour');
```

or make it manually, like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931362/10456235)

Answer (score -4):

My approach is extending the Date.prototype with the following add functionalities:

```
Date.prototype.addYears = Date.prototype.addYears || function (y, supressSet) {
    if (!supressSet) { this.setFullYear(this.getFullYear() + y); return this; }
    return new Date(this).addYears(y);
};
Date.prototype.addDays = Date.prototype.addDays || function (d, supressSet) {
    return this.addHours(d * 24, supressSet);
};
Date.prototype.addHours = Date.prototype.addHours || function (h, supressSet) {
    return this.addMinutes(h * 60, supressSet);
};
Date.prototype.addMinutes = Date.prototype.addMinutes || function (m, supressSet) {
    return this.addSeconds(m * 60, supressSet);
};
Date.prototype.addSeconds = Date.prototype.addSeconds || function (s, supressSet) {
    return this.addMilliseconds(s * 1000, supressSet);
};
Date.prototype.addMilliseconds = Date.prototype.addMilliseconds || function (ms, supressSet) {
    if (!supressSet) { this.setTime(this.getTime() + ms); return this; }
    return new Date(this).addMilliseconds(ms);
};
```

The supressSet parameter is optional and makes the respective function work as a getter without changing the object itself. If ommited, it is evaluated to false, which means the original date object will be modified.

As pointed out in comments I missed to take leap years into account. For that I took and adjusted the solution for months [from Jazaret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13633692/2556142):

```
var DateHelper = {
    isLeapYear: function (year) {
        return (((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0));
    },
    getDaysInMonth: function (dateinput) {
        return [31, (DateHelper.isLeapYear(dateinput.getFullYear()) ? 29 : 28), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][dateinput.getMonth()];
    }
};

Date.prototype.addMonths = function (m, supressSet) {
    var n = this.getDate(),nDate=new Date(this);
    nDate.setDate(1);
    nDate.setMonth(nDate.getMonth() + m);
    nDate.setDate(Math.min(n, DateHelper.getDaysInMonth(nDate)));
    if (!supressSet) {
        this.setDate(nDate.getDate()); this.setMonth(nDate.getMonth());
    }
    return nDate;
};
```

Comment: Extending native prototypes isn't really helpful anymore these days where multiple libraries live in the same namespace. That's what broke popular libraries in the past because they were fighting over who could extend Date, Functiona nd Object with their version of addX.

Comment: also, adding a day **is not always adding 24hours**. That would *somehow*  depend on the timezone, and even in UTC you have leap seconds, which are not taken into account.

Comment: in what timezone doesnt a day have 24 hours? also I would be interested in a reference to the leap second statement please. If I can I will modify then to take that into account. Thank you!

Comment: This seems a rather pointless exercise, and wrong. Adding 1 day is not the same as adding 24 hours where you cross a daylight saving boundary. Also, the way you're adding months means 31 Jan + 1 month will be 2 or 3 March, depending on whether it's a leap year or not. Adding negative months will have similar results: 31 March + -1 month will be 2 or 3 March. You'll get similar results for months with 31 days vs 30.

Comment: If your computer is in a time zone that follows daylight savings time, you can try `.addDays(180)` and the result will be off by 1 hour.

Comment: Leap Years added now. I live in germany and tried to add 100 days several times and the time stays correct...

Comment: @MMMagic Treating a day as = 24 hours isn't correct. https://gist.github.com/jleedev/ab7d17ba92669fab66ae6ec041ec8c1a

Comment: also, adding a month is subjective, and business dependant. If you started some monthly subscription on the 10th of january, you expect your subscription to be renewed on 10th february, 10th march, 10th april etc...  If you subscribed at the end of the month, 31st january, when would it need to be renewed ? 28th feb ? (29th for leap years ?) 1st march ? 2nd march ?

Comment: in a nutshell : date/calendar arithmetic is much much harder than it might appear, and rolling your own will make you fall in a lot of traps, that libraries (kinda) handle more or less smoothly.